# Reactjs rendering twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

In my reactjs project, component is rendered twice. if I remove the componentDidMount, the problem is fixed. But I need it in my project. I tried the solutions on the internet, but I couldn't.

App.js

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(result => {
        this.setState({
          users: result.data
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Home />} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

Home.js

```
export default class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log("Render");
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>console.log render twice</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/wyjk931z6l

console.log works on Home.js twice.

Comment: It will render twice, so what's the problem? this is how api call works

Comment: Please explain why you think that the component being rendered multiple times is somehow bad. Because that's how React works (or any other software that uses a screen).

Answer (score 3):

You App component re-renders because the API call that you make in componentDidMount results in a setState on success. Due to this, the child components also go though a re-render even though their props didn't change. In order to avoid it, you can write the child component by extending `React.PureComponent` which implements the `shouldComponentUpdate` by shallowly comparing the props and state.

```
export default class Home extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    console.log("Render");
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>console.log render twice</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/9575656ky)**

Comment: Good answer, but shouldn't we find out why OP thinks that a non-problem is a problem first? I fear that telling them about `shouldComponentUpdate` might encourage a bad practice that should be avoided in the first place.

Comment: @ChrisG yes you are right, However, I did try to explain what exactly is happening in the OP code, and advised on using PureComponent instead of implementing shouldComponentUpdate himself